# How to save state of checkbox in UserControl c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save the state of checkboxes on my UserControl3. How can such be done? In this I am trying to save them via timer. And then add their save on the UserControl3_Load.

```
private void UserControl3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            materialCheckBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1;
            materialCheckBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2;
            materialCheckBox4.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox3;
        }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1 = materialCheckBox1.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2 = materialCheckBox2.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox3 = materialCheckBox4.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Comment: 1. use `CheckChanged/FormClosing` event instead of timer 2. what is your problem?

Comment: There is no FormClosing/CheckChanged event in UserControl. And the problem is that it is not saving.

Comment: what **scope** are set for the settings?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1ad24dd13cba151bd76cc944682de319

Comment: @RohanPas are you trying with VS or the standalone exe?

Comment: @RezaAghaei The checkboxes are on the usercontrol.

Comment: You need to use property binding to application settings. You can do it using designer or using code. The duplicate answer, is exactly what you need.

Comment: Save them when/wherever you need. Load them using property biding to application settings like linked post. It also supports two-way data binding. As soon as you change the setting property, you can see the change in all bound controls.

Comment: @RezaAghaei How could such be done for bool instead of string?

Comment: When you choose `Checked` property of the `CheckBox` under `(ApplicationSettings)`, the setting property which you create is of type bool.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy. Use `User` as scope.

[image]

UserControl1.cs:

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1;
        checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1 = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2 = checkBox2.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
    }
```

Comment: This is not a form. This is a usercontrol. All the materialcheckboxes are stored on the usercontrol.

Comment: Oh sorry. It works the same.

Comment: There is no Closing event for UserControls though.

Comment: use OnHandleDestroyed event. You have full access to the Control's properties at this moment, because it is not yet disposed of.

Comment: If you use property binding to application settings, you don't need those code in `Load` even of control at all. In your current solution, you will not be notified of change of settings properties and always show initial values, while data binding to application settings support 2-way bindings. See the linked post for more information on how to do it.