# How would I read information from a text file and change checkbox status depending on that information?

Tags: c#, winforms

> ```
>       foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"bin\save.dat"))
>           //Console.WriteLine(line);
>           listBox1.Items.Add(line);
>
>       toggle_one.Checked = (listBox1.Items[1]);
> ```

Obviously this doesn't work. :(

Context:

I want to save users information after they close the app so once they reopen it, their data is saved so they dont need to go through that hassling login process once again.

Ive asked X but it doesnt work, Im trying to use Y but that doesnt work.
Ive read forums about what I want to do, nothing helps.

How would I read information from a text file and change checkbox status depending on that information?

Comment: It's not clear what the expectation is here. Please edit the question, share sample content of the file and explain the expected behavior.

Comment: I'm making a program but I want it to save the users data.

If they click YES on a prompt, it will save YES so they wont need to click it again.
And so they can stay logged in to the program. 
I want to save their data to a text file and use that text file to save their login and their information to my program but I don't know how to do that. I've tried to ask for X   but that didn't work, ive read forums about X but its not exactly what I want. I need help trying to save the users information.

Comment: Please read [ASK] and edit the question, and add the description to the question.

Comment: It's okay, I found a workaround. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487574/save-settings-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp) [and here helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036187/how-to-save-state-of-checkbox-in-usercontrol-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"bin\save.dat"))
    {
      //Console.WriteLine(line);
      //listBox1.Items.Add(line);
      bool state = line == "yes" ? true : false;
      toggle_one.Checked = (state);
    }
```

that's a OTTOMH quick and dirty solution as an example. (replace line comparison to whatever you've saved to indicate user choice for a checkbox)

Comment: thank you, ill try it out

edit:

i have three checkboxes and it only saves my changes if all three checkboxes are checked

Comment: Hi, not saving unless all checked is another question. The code above will set the checkbox to checked/not based on the values you've saved. Do you need me to explain anything in the code snippet?

Comment: is there a way i could set it to save separately  for different checkboxes?

Comment: yes but it is more involved and can be achieved in different ways. For example, you could save the name of the checkbox along with it's state and use the name to retrieve the control before setting the state. To give you a more specific answer you'd have to say more about what you can do with the data file, do you have complete control over it or are you merely reading the values in with no option to add data to the file? Probably you should ask another question for that. Did the code solve your initial problem?

Comment: the code solved my problem with saving everything but it only saves when all the checkboxes are checked. how would i save the name of checkbox with the state and change it based on that?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to say what the problem is. Post a snippet in a different question because it is a different question and I believe it's quite strict here about things like that, though I don't know what any penalties might be other than the question being closed.

Comment: All i have in the project is the code you sent me and the code that saves the file.